# Generating Diffie-hellman parameters (generator)

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, number-theory, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to implement a diffie-hellman key exchange. Let's say I found a large prime number **p** - how can I find a generator **g**?

Restricted by the multiprecision library that I have to use, only a few basic operations (+, *, -, /, pow, modExp, modMult, mod, gcd, isPrime, genRandomPrime, genRandomBits, and a few more) are available.

Would it work to look for a safe prime **q**, so that every number **n** for which `gcd(n,q) == 1` should be a generator, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already gotten the ritual admonishment not to roll your own crypto if you care at all about your security, so here's how to find a generator mod a safe prime q. A number g in the closed range [2, q - 2] is a generator if and only if g^((q-1)/2) != 1 mod q, which you should compute with the standard algorithm for modular exponentiation. Choose random values of g until one passes the test.

Answer (score 3):

You basically answered your question. Just the test `gcd(n,q)==1` is not necessary since `q` is prime. It means that any number `n`, such that `n < q` does not have common factor with `q` and `gcd(n,q)` will always output 1.

You can check whether **q=2p + 1** is prime number. If so, then **ord(Zq) = q-1 = (2p+1)-1 = 2p**. Since **ord(x) | ord(Zq)** for every **x** in **Zq** **ord(x)=2** or **ord(x)=p** or **ord(x)=2p**. Thus you just need to check whether your randomly chosen element **x** from {2,...,q-1} is of order 2. If not then it is of order p or 2p and you can use it as a generator.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule, don't ask programmers questions about cryptography. Cryptography is subtle and, as a result, difficult in invisible ways that lead readily to self-deception about one's own competence. Instead, ask cryptographers (many of which are also programmers). Stack Exchange has a cryptography board, where this question has already been answered.

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/what-diffie-hellman-parameters-should-i-use

I could quibble with the advice there, but it's basically sound. Unless you really want to learn the relevant mathematics, I'd defer to authorities; they're cited in the answer above.

As to the mathematics question you ask, here's a tiny introduction. The multiplicative group modulo a prime *p* has size *p-1*. (See [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).) The [order of any element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) must divide *p-1*. The most favorable case is where *p-1=2q*, where *q* is also prime.

Comment: If you mean by maximal order of an element number q-1 then it is not true that there is no element of maximal order. Imagine simple multiplicative group Z mod 11. ord(2) is 10.

Comment: @MarekKlein I removed the offending claim. I shouldn't do math when I'm distracted.